# Applying for visitor visa from within Canada for Work Permit holder

Tags: visa, canada

I currently hold a valid work permit in Canada. However, I want to attend an event in a month after the expiry of my status in Canada. I am thinking of applying for a visitor visa. Does anyone know if the application of a visitor visa from within Canada while holding a valid work permit is issued for a full 10 years or for a very short period of time? I think it will be economical to get a visa for 10 years rather than being issued for short periods of time.

Comment: As far as I am aware it is not possible to apply for a Canadian visitor visa while you are in Canada.

Comment: @phoog Do you have a source for that? I am not seeing that as an eligibility requirements on CIC's website. https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html Further more, the how to apply page clearly mentions that one can apply for a visitor visa from inside Canada if they meet certain criteria. You can read more about it here: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/apply-new-temporary-resident-visa-within-canada.html

Comment: I read that too, bit I am not sure if I will get a TRV valid for a short time period or a regular visitor visa valid for 10 years

Comment: @pg2455 No one knows that. The only way to find out is to apply.

Comment: @pg2455 According to https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=417&top=16 all visa applicants are automatically considered for a multiple entry visa valid for up to 10 years or one month before your passport expires, whichever is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply to change your status to visitor, but once your current study or work permit expires, you won’t be able to apply for a new study or work permit from within Canada. This means it won’t give you more time to extend your study or work permit.

Most visitors aren’t eligible to apply for a study or work permit from within Canada. If you change your status to visitor, you may have to leave Canada to apply for a new study or work permit.

Because of this, we strongly recommend you don’t change your status to visitor if you need more time to apply for your permit.

https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1503&top=16